# how to create custom list column something like people column?

Tags: sharepoint-list

I wanna to create a list column that is something like "people or group" sharepoint type in sharepoint 2013. I mean I want to create a list column that get a display text value and a url that when user click on it go to a special page, in the same way when you click on for example "Modified By" field value that is a user id you go to a page that show the user information.

Any idea???

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Does the url depend on current user? I mean when user A enters the page the url is http://url/pageA/ and when user B enters the page the url is http://url/pageB/?

Comment: No, It's depend on the list column value, and send the column's value as a parameter to new page.

Answer (score 1):

In [this article](http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/how-to-open-hyperlinks-in-a-new-window-or-not/) you can find info how to create link in sp column using columns' values.
Bassicaly you have to create calculate field and create specific formula which generates expected HTML e.g.

```
=CONCATENATE("<DIV><a href='","http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.",Title,IF([Open in new window?]=TRUE,"' target='_blank' ","'"),">",Title,"</a></DIV>")
```

Comment: Thank you Greg! I read the article, so I added a calculated list to my list, add list to a page and under it I add a content editor webpart. I save the below code in a .txt file and set the URL of content editor webpart URL to use this field, but it didn't work in firefox and in it I get the error: "Object doesn't support this property or method sp.ribbon.debug.js".